# how can i draw lines using mouseclick in opencv in a webcam frame?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to draw a line using mouse-event in Opencv in a webcam frame. I also want to erase it just like an eraser in MS-Paint.How can i do it? I dont have much idea about it. But i have this scrambled pseduo code from my head which can be completely wrong but i will write it down anyway. I would like to know how to implement it in c++.
So, i will have two three mouse event-
event 1- Mouse leftbuttonup-- this will be used to start the drawing
event 2- Mouse move -- this will be used to move the mouse to draw
event 3:- Mouse leftbuttondown-this will be used to stop the drawing.
event 4- Mouse double click - this event i can use to erase the drawing.

I will also have a drawfunction for a line such as line(Mat image,Point(startx,starty),Point(endx,endy),(0,0,255),1));

Now, i dont know how to implement this in a code format. I tried a lot but i get wrong results. I have a sincere request that please suggest me the code in Mat format not the Iplimage format. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried. What do you mean by 'wrong results'? Use opencv's mouse listener to determine where the user clicks. There are plenty of examples.

Comment: @user3791372:- The thing thats bugging me so much is i am unable to figure out how to figure out the start position in Lbuttonup and the end position in Lbuttondown. Most of the articles that i have checked on google using iplimages which confuses me a lot since i follow the Mat format. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: an two element array, a two element structure, a simple class, etc. don't overcomplicate it

Comment: @user3791372:- I am still confused

Comment: Hi Rebecca, Do you want to draw over playing video of webcam or just capture a frame and then draw on it.

Comment: @PervezAlam:- i want to draw over playing video of webcam. Any links  or advise?

Comment: I am little busy, I will give you working code by tomorrow night. It is not complex. For time being, I can advise you to create a blank image of webcam frame size, on which you actually write when mouse moves on video frame. And write/merge this image over every-frame before displaying.

Comment: @PervezAlam:- Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.The fact is that i am having hard time executing any sort of task using the mouse event function. Here is a link of one of my query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550961/how-can-i-get-mouse-cursor-position-by-clicking-on-left-mouse-click. Once i can understand my mistake, i can use the mouse to execute any tasks i want. Thanks again! A sincere request- If you r helping me with the webcam code, please try to use Mat instead of Iplimage format as i really get confused with the latter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

please find working code below with inlined explained comments using Mat ;)
Let me know in case of any problem.

PS: In main function, I have changed defauld cam id to 1 for my code, you should keep it suitable for you PC, probably 0. Good Luck.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>


class WebCamPaint
{
public:

    int cam_id;
    std::string win_name;
    cv::VideoCapture webCam;

    cv::Size frame_size;
    cv::Mat cam_frame, drawing_canvas;

    cv::Point current_pointer, last_pointer;
    cv::Scalar erase_color, paint_color;
    int pointer_size;

    //! Contructor to initialize basic members to defaults
    WebCamPaint()
    {
        cam_id = 0;
        pointer_size = 5;

        win_name = std::string("CamView");
        current_pointer = last_pointer = cv::Point(0, 0);

        erase_color = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        paint_color = cv::Scalar(250, 10, 10);
    }

    //! init function is required to set some members in case default members needed to change. 
    bool init()
    {
        //! Opening cam with specified cam id
        webCam.open(cam_id);
        //! Check if problem opening video
        if (!webCam.isOpened())
        {
            return false;
        }

        //! Reading single frame and extracting properties
        webCam >> cam_frame;
        //! Check if problem reading video
        if (cam_frame.empty())
        {
            return false;
        }
        frame_size = cam_frame.size();
        drawing_canvas = cv::Mat(frame_size, CV_8UC3);

        //! Creating Activity / Interface window
        cv::namedWindow(win_name);
        cv::imshow(win_name, cam_frame);

        //! Resetting drawing canvas
        drawing_canvas = erase_color;

        //! initialization went successful ;)
        return true;
    }

    //! This function deals wih all processing, drawing and displaying ie main UI to user
    void startAcivity()
    {
        //! Keep doing until user presses "Esc" from Keyboard, wait for 20ms for user input
        for (char user_input = cv::waitKey(20); user_input != 27; user_input = cv::waitKey(20))
        {
            webCam >> cam_frame;    //Read a frame from webcam

            cam_frame |= drawing_canvas;    //Merge with actual drawing canvas or drawing pad, try different operation to merge incase you want different effect or solid effect
            cv::imshow(win_name, cam_frame);    //Display the image to user

            //! Change size of pointer using keyboard + / -, don't they sound fun ;)
            if (user_input == '+' && pointer_size < 25)
            {
                pointer_size++;
            }
            else if (user_input == '-' && pointer_size > 1)
            {
                pointer_size--;
            }
        }
    }

    //! Our function that should be registered in main to opencv Mouse Event Callback
    static void onMouseCallback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
    {
        /* NOTE: As it will be registered as mouse callback function, so this function will be called if anything happens with mouse
         *          event   :   mouse button event
         *          x, y    :   position of mouse-pointer relative to the window
         *          flags   :   current status of mouse button ie if left / right / middle button is down
         *          userdata:   pointer o any data that can be supplied at time of setting callback,
         *                      we are using here to tell this static function about the this / object pointer at which it should operate
        */

        WebCamPaint *object = (WebCamPaint*)userdata;

        object->last_pointer = object->current_pointer;
        object->current_pointer = cv::Point(x, y);

        //! Drawing a line on drawing canvas if left button is down
        if (event == 1 || flags == 1)
        {
            cv::line(object->drawing_canvas, object->last_pointer, object->current_pointer, object->paint_color, object->pointer_size);
        }

        //! Drawing a line on drawing canvas if right button is down
        if (event == 2 || flags == 2)
        {
            cv::line(object->drawing_canvas, object->last_pointer, object->current_pointer, object->erase_color, object->pointer_size);
        }
    }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WebCamPaint myCam;
    myCam.cam_id = 1;
    myCam.init();
    cv::setMouseCallback(myCam.win_name, WebCamPaint::onMouseCallback, &myCam);
    myCam.startAcivity();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: :- Thanks so much. I really appreciate it. You have helped me a lot. Thanks again. Bdw can you recommend me any books for Opencv using c++, so that i can learn some complicated programs. I am basically a self learner as i am a freshman and so i need a book which explains the concepts clearly. Thanks again

Comment: I am glad it helped. I assume you understood and learnt from this code. About further study, OpenCV is amazing library and great resources. If you just google, you will find a lots of book, codes etc. I recommend you to start from official doc: http://opencv.org/documentation.html . This page has link to all code-doc and ref, books, tutorials and more. You can go with oreilly book, it is going to launch new edition soon. If it helped, you can upvote/accept this answer, it help other readers see the rating of answer.