# How can i get Mouse Cursor position by clicking on left mouse click?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am really having hard time implementing the mouse event function. I was asked to read the following link by one of the stackexchange users [Drawing rectangle or line using mouse events in open cv using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140880/drawing-rectangle-or-line-using-mouse-events-in-open-cv-using-python). So, when i went through the following link, i understood the code but then i wanted to write a simple program such that whenever the user clicks on his/her left click, the position of the mouse is shown in the console window. Now, here is my code. One thing that confuses me, is that not only i get a blank window with no mouse position but also i have this question that i have to ask the user to press the left mouse button and then the mousecallbackfunction should execute. Thats where i think i am doing wrong because i am not giving the user the option to click on the leftclick and the program executes without that option. Is there any way of fixing it? Here is my code. Please correct me. I need to understand this thing because i have to excute some complicated tasks using the mouse event function. So, i need to fully grasp the concept and understand where i am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
bool clicked = false;
int x,y;
POINT Q;

void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int f, void* )
      {
            switch(event) {
            case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                    clicked = true;
                    GetCursorPos(&Q);
                    x = Q.x;
                    y = Q.y;

                    cout<<"The position of the mouse is:"<<x<<y<<endl;
                    break;

               default:
                break;

            }
      }

int main()
{
cout<<"Mouse event program"<<endl;
setMouseCallback("Mouseposition",onMouse,NULL);
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this with WinAPI or just OpenCV? You don't have any "window/gui" code there..

Comment: @Brandon:- i am using openCV. But i wouldn't mind using WinAPI. Can you kindly tell me where did i do wrong in my above code?

Comment: Hmya, this tends to be a rude awakening.  Sure, that callback is never going to run.  Your program is *catatonic*, unaware of what the user is trying to do.  Stuck in that system() call, nothing happens until the user presses the Enter key.  Creating an interactive program that is responsive to a mouse requires a very different programming style, an *event driven* style.  It is going to take you a while to get there, it is very unlikely the cout/cin programming model that C++ supports.  The quicky fix in this case is replacing system("pause") with waitKey(0).

Comment: As [shown here](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2011/11/mouse-events.html).

Comment: @HansPassant:- Thank you! finally a way out!!sRSLY thanks from the core of my heart.